# RegEx get all characters between space and specified string

Tags: c#, regex

New to RegEx expressions I'm trying to get a file name that is between whitespace and the end of the file extension.

The string I'm dealing with is like so:

> abcdefg 3255 Jul  1 14:14 **thefile.txt**asdfdsgs-

I'm trying to retrieve the text `thefile.txt` but can't find anything that will select `.txt` and everything before until the whitespace.

Basically, I'm looking for anything that has `.txt` and all characters before it until it reaches a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this Regex helps you further:

```
Regex rex = new Regex(@"\b\w+\.txt");
```

Just tried and it worked for me.

Comment: The `\b` isn't needed. `\w` won't capture a whitespace character, and it's guaranteed to be on a word boundary there.

Comment: This worked the way I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx will work:

```
(\S+\.txt)
```

Check this [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/PAJflpyhFm) to see it in action

Comment: The capture group isn't needed

Comment: Rubular is for testing Ruby regexps, use RegexStorm.net or RegexHero.net to test .NET regexps. Also, `\S+` will also match `.`, I'd use `[^\s.]+`.